# How to use each in jQuery for all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to apply this code to any element that has my data attribute on it. I could only get it working, when I would put in a class or id. How can I loop through all elements? Thank you!

```
$(".section").each(function() {
     var dataHeight = $(this).data("min-height");
     var dataPercent = dataHeight / 100;
     $(this).css("min-height", function() {
          return $(window).height() * dataPercent;
     });
});
```

Comment: Just use the attribute selector `$("[data-min-height]")`. Shouldn’t this work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wdhmLLcL/1/

Comment: Wow, no idea why I did not think of that. Thank you so much.,